# Symfony2.3 production page blank 500

Tags: php, symfony, apc, dev-to-production

after working with my project on dev mod, i found some problems with prod on OVH.
it shows me a blank page ! i try to follow the issue on app.php and i found that the problem persist with the execution of `$response = $kernel->handle($request);` and it don't logging on prod.

so when i change the row on app.php : `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);` with `$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', false);` it works well !!!

here's my app.php

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the Sonata package.
 *
 * (c) Thomas Rabaix <thomas.rabaix@sonata-project.org>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */
umask(0000);
require_once __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
require_once __DIR__ . '/../app/AppKernel.php';

//use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

// if you want to use the SonataPageBundle with multisite
// using different relative paths, you must change the request
// object to use the SiteRequest
use Sonata\PageBundle\Request\SiteRequest as Request;

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);

$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

EDIT :
in dev and prod local mode test it works well with

```
 php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug 
php app/console assets:install web_directory 
php app/console assetic:dump web_directory
```

should i add or install php5 on my project ?

**EDIT :**
my project contains : sonata-project, fosUserBundle,etc...

**EDIT**

the problem was on config_prod.xml

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                metadata_cache_driver: apc
                query_cache_driver:    apc
                result_cache_driver:   apc
```

intil now after it return an error 500 ! why ? because of apc was not enabled !
so my question how to enable apc on OVH pro !

Comment: as far as I remember you have to `cache:clear --env=prod`

Comment: you should go into your php.ini and turn on displayerrors.  it will tell you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: Since it's production, you should enable php log in php.ini instead of showing errors on display.

Comment: how to enable it ? and where i should findd this file ?
there's my .htaccess : SetEnv SHORT_OPEN_TAGS 0
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0
SetEnv MAGIC_QUOTES 0
SetEnv SESSION_AUTOSTART 0
SetEnv ZEND_OPTIMIZER 1
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_4
SetEnv SESSION_USE_TRANS_SID 0

Comment: config.php : This script is only accessible from localhost.

Comment: @dalu i cleared the cache but nothing showing on log prod !

Comment: In php.ini: `log_errors = On` and `error_log = /path/to/my/php_error.log`

Comment: i can't locate php.ini but in https://logs.ovh.net/xx.com on 
error/xx-19-10-2014.log.gz : no errors;
logs/xx-19-10-2014.log.gz : xx..xxx..xxx xxxjrv.cluster007.ovh.net - [19/Oct/2014:23:07:25 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 26 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/xx.0.xxx.104 Safari/537.36"

Comment: i can't locate exactly where is the problem.. would you specify to me exactly the name file

Comment: sorry Mirlo I can't. Not a ovh customer. I assumed you have access to the php configuration. On many Linux distros php.ini is found in /etc/php5/php.ini or similar locations. I currently don't know if those options are settable at runtime. Look it up in the manual.

Comment: i have try anohter solution which  that may help you :
on app.php i change $kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false); with 
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', false); so it worked ? so where's the problem exactly !

Answer (score 0):

Go to web/config.php and comment ot the following lines:

```
if (!in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array(
    '127.0.0.1',
    '::1',
))) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('This script is only accessible from localhost.');
}
```

That will enable the config.php to be called from "extern". Don't forget to remove the comments after you've checked everything.

If you have console access on the production server, enter the root directory of your project and call `php app/check.php` to run the checks on the console.

Comment: the config.php works  well when i comment those lines, i don't have the console access..but when i followed the app.php and when it reached the line $response = $kernel->handle($request);  it blocks and return to me a blank page !